# How can I loop over file names and conditionally delete the file in bash

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm having a problem where I need to delete all files/folders in my project directory using a bash script except two folders "node_modules" and "build". I've tried doing it like this but no luck

```bash
for file in * ; do 
file_name = "$file"
if ( "$file_name" != "node_modules" && "$file_name"!="build") then 
echo $file 
fi 

done ;
```

Comment: Copy-paste your code in [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: Are `node_modules` and `build` in the current directory or any subdirectory?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes the node_modules and build are in the current directory

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on bash scripting, you have several basic syntax errors.

Comment: Your script isn't valid Bash syntax. There should be no spaces around the equal sign in the assignment to `file_name`. The `if` expression should be enclosed in square brackets, not parenthesis. You should probably spend a couple of hours to learn the basics of Bash syntax.

Comment: You can't have spaces around `=` in an assignment, you need to use `[]` rather than `()` around the condition, you have to have spaces around `!=`

Comment: There's also no need for the `file_name` variable, you can just use `$file`.

Comment: One way to do it is to use Bash's [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) feature: `shopt -s extglob; rm -r -- !(node_modules|build)`.

Comment: Please first make your script syntactically correct. It is pointless discussing the **effect** of code which still has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`:

```
for file_name in *; do
  if [[ "$file_name" != "node_modules" ]] && [[ "$file_name" != "build" ]]; then
    echo rm -r "$file_name";
  fi;
done
```

or

```
GLOBIGNORE="node_modules:build"
echo rm -r *
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work
`[[` and `space` is matter in if statement.

Save as `delete.sh` file name.

```bash
for file in * ;
do 
    # Not delete two directories
    if [[ -d "$file" &&  "$file" == "node_modules" || "$file" == "build" ]];
    then
        echo "save directory: ""$file"
    else
        # Not delete delete.sh
        if [[ "$file" == "delete.sh" ]];
        then
            echo "not delete myself: ""$file"
        else
            # delete other directory and sub files
            if [[ -d "$file" ]];
            then
                rm -rf "$file"
            else
                rm "$file"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done ;
```

Run it

```bash
chmod u+x delete.sh

./delete.sh
```

Add the executable bit to the owner of the file while ignoring the umask

In terminal

[image]

Before

[image]

After run `delete.sh`

[image]

Comment: I suggest to add a shebang to your script and execute `chmod u+x delete.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to be sure they are actually directories

```
find -d . ! \( -type d -and \( -name build -or -name node_modules \) \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```